# 2D Tile-Based Concept Art App

Tags: art

I'm making a bunch of 2D games (now and in the near future) that use a 2D, RPG-like interface. I would like to be able to quickly paint tiles down and drop character sprites to create concept art.

Sure, I could do it in GIMP or Photoshop. But that would require manually adding each tile, layering on more tiles, cutting and pasting particular character sprites, etc. and I really don't need that level of granularity; I need a quick and fast way to churn out concept art.

Is there a tool that I can use for this? Perhaps some sort of 2D tile editor which lets me draw sprites and tiles given that I can provide the graphics files.

Comment: i've wrote a little "TileViewer" app in c# for those purposes, if you want i could send it to you ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you seen [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/)?  I've used it for this very purpose myself a number of times.

From the website:

> - General purpose tile map editor with XML-based map format
> - Supports orthogonal and isometric maps
> - Custom objects can be placed with pixel precision
> - Full undo/redo and copy/paste support
> - Add custom properties to tiles, layers, objects or the map
> - Automatically reloads tilesets when changed externally
> - Resize or offset your tile map later as needed
> - Efficient tile editing tools like stamp and fill brushes
> - Supports input/output plugins to open and save files in custom formats

This program is a fantastic tool for laying out tile-based maps very quickly, with lots of flexibility.  When finished, it can even render your map to an image file.

There's also [Mappy](http://tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php).  Though I have no real experience with this tool, it does appear to have similar features.

Comment: +1 tiled looks good. I'll check it out in more detail tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Ogmo Editor](http://www.ogmoeditor.com/) for this purpose. It's similar to `Tiled`, but it's simpler hence it has less features.

I was very satisfied with it, but now the version 2 has been released and I haven't tried it yet. Here's a [video tutorila](http://flashpunk.net/2011/05/episode-4-setting-up-the-ogmo-editor-to-create-content/) for the older version.

Comment: From the tutorials, it looks quite a bit harder to use. Thanks for mentioning it though.